# Where can I see what kind of questions are or are not relevant on /programmers?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, help-center

Where can I see what kind of questions are or are not relevant on /programmers?

From usability point of view, it's pretty hard to find.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted)

Comment: side note I've seen "hidden site scope" [explained as sort of by-design](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7156/how-to-make-this-question-about-blogging-more-useful#comment21442_7156) "...Kinda, _first you try and break your nose and after that we'll tell you to look at [help/on-topic]_"

Answer (score 5):

The [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help) has all the information that you need. Specifically, check out these pages:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

If you aren't sure if your question is on-topic or if you need help to narrow down the scope or make other improvements, you can always ask here on Meta or in [the chat room, The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).

Comment: FWIW I feel that [Workplace's help/on-topic](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is laid out better than our, in that items in their "not about" list are conveniently linked to respective detailed explanations on their meta. Ours are plain statements, even though we have an excellent meta FAQ with appropriately structured answers that we could link them at [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted)

Comment: @gnat - do you want to write up a suggested edit as a meta question and one of us can make the edit?

Comment: good idea @ChrisF - thanks! I will try to figure how to do such an edit. This will take some time, and I will probably post a draft here at meta for review

Comment: @ChrisF there you go - suggested edit draft is [posted here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7236/help-center-tuning-help-on-topic-and-it-is-not-about-references-to-meta) for review

Comment: Pardon me but where is that Help Centre? I can't see any link. Neither from the home page nor from the ask question page.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek At the header of the page, there's a menu labeled "help". If you click that, there's a link to the Help Center. There's also a "help" link in the footer of the page.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek There's also a link in the ask question page: http://i.stack.imgur.com/giqqI.png