# New Site Name and Scope Proposals

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, site-definition, new-site-name

From [Ana, a Stack Exchange Community Manager](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/106878/ana?tab=profile) in [the previous question about changing the site name](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7935/4):

> It took us a good while, but the Community Team has circled up and
> here's where we stand on your request to change Programmers.SE's name.
>
> #### We agree that renaming this site is a good idea.
>
> "Programmers" is an affinity group, whereas "Software Architecture"
> (for example) is an action and a discipline. It is entirely possible
> that changing the site's name will send clearer signals and prime new
> users to ask questions more consistently in line with what y'all would
> be proud to see and answer, particularly given where this site’s scope
> has solidified over the past few years.
>
> *So yes, we're open to proceeding with a name change.* That said, we'll need to make sure the change makes the kind of difference you
> want it to, because we can't repeat this process again several years
> down the line. We gotta get it right *this* time. Last time the site
> was renamed, the scope was very much still in flux; by now, hopefully
> you can identify much more precisely *what this site is about* and
> commit to both a name *and* description *and* introductory materials
> that communicate this body of knowledge clearly and succinctly.
>
> #### Here's what the Community Team needs before we can move forward:
>
> 1. **Tell us what you're proposing as the new site name.**
>
>    "Software Engineering" and "Software Architecture" both look like
>    good options from where I stand. Let’s not turn this into a bikeshed
>    discussion; we need well-considered options here, not a popularity
>    contest - Coffee McWhiskeyface is right out. The ideal name will
>    suggest *at a glance* what this site is about, without suggesting that
>    it might be “fix my code” even a little bit.
> 2. **Lay out what the [new site scope](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) will be.**
>
>    Above all else, **the scope needs to be simple**. Seriously. No
>    more than four bullets, no multi-line comma-separated lists, no
>    gerrymandering - **it needs to be easy for any new visitor who bothers
>    to read** and even mildly pays attention to what they're reading to
>    know what they can and cannot ask about here. Eliminate ambiguity for
>    a first time poster once and for all.
>
> Let's talk again in a month.

Let's start answering the following questions:

- What should our site name be?
- What should [our tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) say? Specifically, the first paragraph below the site title that begins with "Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site..."
- What should our [Help Center's on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) say about what is on and off-topic? Note that what this site is about and not about also does appear on the tour.

Comment: I approve of this message ;)

Comment: @ThomasOwens: What is "Engineering Management?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey (Did you mean to leave that on my answer?) It's the application of economics, accounting, organizational behavior, product and project management, and leadership to engineering projects and organizations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_management

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, it. I don't agree with "Engineering management is considered to be a subdiscipline of industrial engineering/systems engineering." But that's only based on how I see Systems Engineering defined where I am now. It could be more generally true.

Comment: I like the idea of changing the name but can we keep the coffee cup?

Comment: I like the name change and I'm convincing it will help this community. Software Engineering seems to be a popular name. There seems to be also much consensus on the scope to remain mostly what it was. A possible new UI design seems to be a bit unclear still - maybe it could be further refined in a separate question.

Comment: Who voted to close this as primarily opinion-based? Yes, it is POB: _that is intentional and good in this case_.

Comment: @Snowman: There's always that one guy that has that completely inane close vote reason....

Comment: It may be useful to remind everyone the whole premise behind changing the site's name was that doing so would make it instantly clearer what's on-topic here. If we're just going to end up with 9 paragraphs explaining what can and can't be asked here, changing the name is pointless.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I second your idea...

Comment: So how is it proceeding from here? Should we create a "new site name and scope proposal" (the highest voted with additions from second highest and third highest maybe) and have a vote whether we really want that as a new site name and scope? Or what else should happen?

Comment: @Trilarion We'll see when SE comes back. There are no objections that I can see to the proposed name of Software Engineering, which, along with any theme changes, is what SE must do. Creating an Interstitial Page is also something that SE would need to do, but again, there doesn't seem to be significant disagreement over the content of that. The Help Center is something that any moderator can do. If you have any objections, I'd recommend leaving an answer here, but I don't think there is a next step until SE comes back.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Hm, as I understood it, SE was asking the Programmers Community for a proposal of a site name and new scope. We have kind of done that here. However, do we just take: a) the highest voted one, b) the average of the highest voted ones, c) battle it out between the highest voted ones, d) test if we really want to do it with a yes/no question on the highest voted one? I wonder if you we should do any of this before we need to wait for SE to come back to us? Basically I ask: what is the official new site name proposal and scope of the community?

Comment: @Trilarion The accepted community wiki answer here serves that purpose. It combines the most accepted portions of the top answers.

Comment: I think success in this matter should be measured (at least) by whether users very familiar with StackOverflow will subsequently find it abundantly easy to know whether their question goes on SO or on the renamed Programmers.  I currently have to ponder about the choice sometimes (programmers are who use SO!), and a rename should make that decision difficult to get wrong.

Comment: I think the current title is fine, the suggestions seem too technical sounding.

Comment: @EvanCarslake We are a technical site. We need to make that more clear to new users who don't get that impression.

Comment: Quick pseudo-update ([originally posted](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7935/4-years-later-dear-stack-exchange-can-we-change-our-site-name/8054#comment25055_8054) under the answer that led to this post): Sorry for the delay, but we may need another week or two. In addition to the "we're busy with multiple things at once" reason (which is both true and not at all unusual), it seems the fact that we're a distributed team has been no barrier to many of us recently getting sick all at once, which hasn't helped matters. We definitely haven't forgotten about the request, though!

Comment: @Pops Thanks. Can you tell us if what we have is sufficient to meet the things Ana was looking for? Or should we use this next week or two to do anything else? It seems like we're coming to consensus on most of the important things that we'd like to see.

Comment: @ThomasOwens It looks nice to me, both on its own and with respect to the guidance above, but __huge caveat__, I'm not that familiar with the history of this process and in this instance my opinion doesn't necessarily represent the rest of the team. I don't know of anything else you should actively be doing. Ana may have more comments in a few days. (I just read that back to myself and realized it's probably not as helpful as I wanted it to be... sorry. I'd rather be noncommittal than wrong, though.)

Comment: @Pops Thanks, that's good enough for now. Looking forward to hearing back in the next few days/weeks.

Comment: To tell the truth, kinda liked the idea of Coffee McWhiskeyface... bummer...

Comment: Just letting folks know we're not absentee, we just had a rather busy last 30 days. The direction here is _really_ good; we'll be chiming in very shortly regarding some of the points that folks have made, and see where we can go from there.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks, looking forward to the next steps.

Comment: Can't we just change it to ... *brogrammers* 

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This answer is to summarize the requests for Stack Exchange in a single post. It is a community wiki, so if something else seems to be a consensus in this thread, feel free to add or edit it.

---

### Name

Change to **Software Engineering**

---

### Tour / Tag Line

#### Welcome

**Software Engineering** is a question and answer site for people involved in the [Systems Development Life Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) who care about creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly. We don't address questions about debugging code or how to use specific tools in software development. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about software development.

#### Ask About

- the systems development life cycle

#### Don't Ask About

- writing or debugging code
- support for software tools or packages
- what to read, learn, buy or use
- legal advice

---

### On Topic Page

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> **Software Engineering** is a question and answer site for people involved in the [Systems Development Life Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) who care about creating, delivering, and maintaining software responsibly.
>
> **If you have a question about...**
>
> - software development [methods and practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process)
> - [requirements engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements)
> - software [architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture) and [design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design)
> - [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) and [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)
> - [quality assurance and testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance)
> - [configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management), [build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) and [release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_management) management
>
> ... then you're probably in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please make sure that your question is not [too broad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) or [strongly
> rooted in opinions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build). If you have questions that warrant an extended
> discussion, feel free to [come to chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_management).
>
> Before asking, [look around](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process) to see if your question has been
> asked. If you see similar questions, be sure to check out their
> answers and differentiate your question from other, related questions.
>
> If you still aren't sure, you can ask about our scope on [our Meta site](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/). We have [a curated FAQ on our Meta site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_management). You can also check out [our list of related sites within the Stack Exchange network](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/i-have-a-question-but-it-may-not-fit-best-on-programmers-where-else-can-i-ask).

Comment: I think the interstitial page needs to be more like Server Fault's. It looks like Server Fault's page is the /help/how-to-ask page. I would like to see a different order here, though. It should go "be on-topic", "be specific", "make it relevant to others", "keep an open mind", and "search, and research".

Comment: @ThomasOwens at SF these are two _different_ pages, [we already discussed this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/new-site-name-and-scope-proposals/8065#comment24880_8061) :)

Comment: @gnat OK. Either way, I don't want a list of things on-topic here on the interstitial unless mods can edit it. I don't want to bug SE if we want to clarify wording in the future. The idea is good, for sure. Especially given the changes we're going through.

Comment: @ThomasOwens so far I have seen rather skeptical assessments of the interstitial efficiency. Though these were coming from SE team folks who generally disliked this feature at smaller sites in the past. Probably works checking with SF moderators are they satisfied with how it works for them. (I recently noticed that unlike Programmers SF doesn't require registration to ask. But still, their pages look so much cleaner than ours, what kind of magic do they use?)

Comment: A six-paragraph interstitial is a bit excessive.

Comment: @Shog9 It does look a lot smaller when put in the main site font, about half the length if I remember correctly (ie. 4 lines becomes 2). We've encountered this discrepancy before with the FAQ and On Topic page. That said, maybe we could remove the bullet points and just link to the On Topic page instead if you want it shorter :)

Comment: @Shog9 As a side note, what *does* the ServerFault page contain that is custom? Is it the entire 6 section text, or just the area above the Ask Question box?

Comment: IIRC, it's one short paragraph at the top.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok, thanks. I was thinking about it, and honestly I think after the name change this really won't be needed. I'd like to keep it as an option for consideration if things don't change, but I really think we won't need it.

Comment: @Shog9: Are you referring to the interstitial page [I have written here?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/8061/1204).  I've already cut it down to as short as I think I can possibly make it.  We might be able to get it down to two paragraphs, but it won't include the friendly fluff, and it won't say anything about what *is* on-topic.  I figure [we have *one chance* to present the critical stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661) in a way that new users can't say they haven't seen it.  They can figure out everything else later.

Comment: @RobertHarvey since site-specific part is mod editable, we can simply use it to highlight most-annoying off-topic of the day ("cr@p du jour" if you wish) and update when needed. At least it seems to be the way SF folks use it: their help/on-topic lists 6 bullets but interstitial picks one of them: "...make sure that it is about managing information technology systems in a business environment. _If your question concerns personal equipment, try asking on Super User instead_."

Comment: "Q&A site for students, practitioners, and researchers of software engineering and related fields" I would not use the term 'students' as this would indicate that homework is relevant. I do know 'students' is linked to 'of software engineering', people less well versed in the english language will not.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I still don't think we need an interstitial page after the name change, or that it needs to be that long. That's why I left it out of this answer. I think it's something that should be addressed separately from the Name/FAQ change.

Comment: @Rachel It isn't that long after you use more width of a page and a smaller font, like the ServerFault page. It's also a good idea to do everything at once, especially with our history, we don't want people claiming ignorance. There's absolutely no way to do that now.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I won't edit it out again, but I think it should be discussed separately. I didn't realize the site [already has a bunch of extra content](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?) for new users asking questions, and adding a huge wall of text to air our history doesn't seem necessary. I think that rebranding the name should be a fresh start, and we shouldn't start trying to explain our history to everyone if it isn't needed.

Comment: @Rachel: New users [never see that material](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/usability-issues-for-first-time-stack-exchange-users-a-micro-study).  The interstitial page is the only chance we have to make our case to new users who choose to post random crap, either deliberately or out of ignorance.  An interstitial guarantees that they can no longer claim ignorance.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't realize this at first, but we can add `/advice` to the end of any Ask Question page to view how it actually looks for new users. I don't think the question you just posted addresses this at all, although [in the comments I agree this page is very useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/#comment906882_279666). I really don't think we need to air our old dirty laundry for new users  with a list of what not to ask at this point though, and it should instead just be something short and simple that tells the user *"hey we have rules! Read them before posting"*

Comment: @Rachel: I'm fascinated by the reluctance (by both you and the folks at SE corporate) to tell people right up front what they need to know to be successful at using the site.  Which do you suppose is more frustrating: being told privately what not to do up front before asking, or being chastised publicly by gnat *after* asking?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree with you that we should have a *short* blurb about the Ask Question DOs and DONTs at the point of asking a question for users. What I think needs more discussion is the actual wording. The wording you proposed is great for a site titled "Programmers", however I am not sure that it is all needed for a site named "Software Engineering". I'd like to discuss that separately, and not mix it in with a summary of our Name/On-Topic changes for SE.

Comment: @Rachel: I have two concerns about the length, and only two: it should all fit on one page (on a 1080p monitor), and the most important stuff should be at the top, where it is most likely to be read.  Compare with http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, which is longer but would still make a perfectly good interstitial.  Beyond that, I'm not all that sympathetic to viewpoints like "a maximum of four bullets."  If you think this is long, you should have seen WSOiN (which really was too long).

Comment: @Rachel: The "What We're Not" section is already condensed as much as I think I can make it without losing information.  You could lose the "So what can I ask" section, I suppose (I already told Thomas Owens I was willing to lose that section if it's *solely about length* and there is no other way), but frankly I think it's useful to state the scope in the interstitial.  Remember, the interstitial is the only thing that new users are likely to see.

Comment: @Rachel: Finally, you seem quite confident that a name change and a name change alone will fix the problem.  It won't.  The name change is essential, but it requires more than that; it requires that users be informed when they ask a question, and the way you do that is by informing them.  Frankly, I'm a bit puzzled why you're opposed to that.  It can't just be about length.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I reread it a few times, and it doesn't go into our past history as much as I thought it did, and isn't bad in its current form :) As for length, I was thinking more in the context of the [full /advice page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice). It would be nice if we could see how your text would fit into the existing page. This kind of page is definitely needed though, and I know I posted something years ago on meta.SE about how our ask question page should be more like reddits with a simple upfront list of dos and donts...

Comment: @RobertHarvey And yes, I am quite confident that a name change with significantly help. I'm not saying it will fix everything, but I am confident it will greatly reduce the number of off topic questions we get. :)

Comment: `Quality Assurance and Testing` -> sqa.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm concerned that the proposed tagline, "... is a question and answer site for students...", will lead us to be inundated with homework problems.  I'd recommend something more like "... is a question and answer site for professional software engineers and those interested in the field".

Comment: @GrandmasterB Personally I think students are welcome here, including their homework questions, as long as they are ontopic and follow the other rules for questions. I just copied what the other answers had though, and the tag line was from [Thomas Owen's answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/8064/1130) and copied from other CS sites. Perhaps leave a comment to voice your concerns to him there?

Comment: I would just change the order. "students, practitioners, and researchers" to "practitioners, researchers and students". Clearly, practitioners should outnumber the other two categories.

Comment: @Trilarion Sounds good, I made the modification

Comment: That's 50% more bullet points than they wanted. I would suggest to get rid of the algorithms and data structures bullet point as that's more in the domain of Data Science SE anyway.

Comment: @Hack-R: data science SE is still a beta, and its scope (though not clearly defined on their help page) looks to me much more restricted. Moreover, "algorithms and data structures" was always a topic which fits well to the conceptual programming focus of "Programmer's", and it IMHO should be also a valid topic on  "Software Engineering.SE".

Comment: I think you could omit "algorithms and data structures" from the bullet list without too much loss.  Conciseness is a virtue.  Many algorithms and data structures questions would probably be better off on [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) (not Data Science), so I think you could remove that from the bullet list without harm.  I'm not trying to argue you change your scope or make those questions out-of-scope; I'm just trying to help you shorten the bullet list, and arguing that you could omit it without great loss.

Comment: I suggest you make the interstitial more concise.  The more concise it is, the more people will read it.  It needs more focus, to focus on the one or two most common problems.  Three suggestions towards that goal: (1) move the sentence "We're not a forum; don't expect things to work the same way as other forums do." to right before "We don't answer survey questions...", and delete "It's always a good idea to survey the landscape of a new site before participating. Take a few moments to familiarize yourself with the site and its participants."

Comment: (2) Change the entire bit "You can ask ... for more details." to just one sentence saying "See What topics can I ask about here? for a description of what topics you can ask about."  (3) Delete "We don't give legal advice", as it's not a common enough problem to be worth adding here.  (These are all separable and you could implement one or more without implementing the other, if one of these is too controversial.)

Comment: I think that you should also write the "do not ask" page. The scope doesn't mention license-y kind of questions, which is one of the biggest grips.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Is the UI even up for change? I didn't see it mentioned in the quote in the question. If it is up for change I think it's better discussed in a separate question.

Comment: @CaptainMan I would assume so. The logo is changing to reflect the new name. Some level of effort to change the graphic design. This whole thing is about rebranding the site to better indicate what we are about. If SE says that it's off the table, it's off the table. If it's on the table, I suspect it will be like other sites coming out of beta - a graphic designer will do something, post it on Meta, and get community feedback.

Comment: Ana said _"No more than four bullets, no multi-line comma-separated lists, no gerrymandering"_. That has been violated several times in the proposed text.

Comment: "Software Engineering"? Really? Is that "SE"? Or is that "SE.SE"? This won't be confusing at all!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's changed a bit since the [first revision](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/8065/1).... it's a community wiki, so anyone can edit. Personally I think trying to limit to 4 bullets is too few for the site scope, but I do think the current version listed could use some pruning again...

Comment: @Rachel: Anyone can edit regardless of community wiki status. I don't really care whose fault it is, I'm just pointing out that this answer in its current form violates the requirements set forth by Stack Exchange.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: just because Ana wishes that does not mean it will be possible. The experts of this community here have a strong idea about what the focus of the site is, and restricting it to four bullet points will always mean to leave out an important part which belongs to minimum basic definition of software engineering.

Comment: In regards to the complete SDLC. You missed the part beyond testing! While I would say it's mainly documentation, others would also include sunset evaluations and ongoing maintenance. These are absolutely part of S.E. in both education and practical application.

Answer (score 147):

### Software Engineering.

I think it's as good a site title as you're going to get.  Here's why:

1. It's *not* "Programmers," which smacks of `people who write teh codez.`
2. Electrical Engineering's name change (from Electronics) was very good for them.  It raised the quality bar on that site significantly.

#### The On-Topic page, Tour Page, or Whatever New Users See First™

Frankly, after watching this site for as long as I have, I strongly believe that we should lead with a brief summary of *what we're not.*  We can caution people right up front while still keeping it light and friendly.  Something like this:

> ### Welcome to Software Engineering!
>
> We'd love to help you out with your Software Engineering question.  But before you ask your question, please read the important stuff below.
>
> **We don't do code troubleshooting here,** so if your question is about how to fix your broken code or how to use your programming tools, ask it on Stack Overflow, making sure that you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
>
> We don't answer survey questions, make lists of things, or engage in extended discussion here.  We don't predict the future, find things on the Internet, provide customer support, or make product recommendations of any kind here.  We don't know what project you should do next, what class you should take next, or what job you should apply for.  We don't give legal advice.
>
> Phew.  *That was close!*
>
> #### OK, So what ***can*** I ask?
>
> You can ask Software Engineering questions *directly related to the Software Development Life Cycle,* including:
>
> - Software Development Methods and Practices
> - Requirements Engineering
> - Software Architecture and Design
> - Algorithms and Data Structures
> - Quality Assurance and Testing
> - Configuration, Build and Release Management
>
> If it's not in that list, it's probably off-topic.
>
> It's always a good idea to survey the landscape of a new site before participating.  Take a few moments to familiarize yourself with the site and its participants.  **We're not a forum;** don't expect things to work the same way as other forums do.
>
> Good luck, and **welcome to Software Engineering!**

Finally, this needs to be an *interstitial page,* something that is put right in front of people before they ask their first question, with a checkbox at the bottom that says

```
☑  I have read and understand this page. No, really. I have.
```

ServerFault did something similar; we can do the same.

Comment: I rarely upvote (or downvote) an answer to a question that I have also answered. This is one of those cases. You address the "don'ts" very well which I think is important, and licensing is not on the on-topic list. You enumerate the guardrails we need to put up, and cite other Stack Exchange sites as examples that implemented those guardrails with success. Great ideas.

Comment: This answer is beautiful.

Comment: Really like this.  My only concern is 'Software Requirements'.  I'd be worried it would be interpreted as 'what kind of software do I need to...'.  Is there a different term that can be used for it?

Comment: @GrandmasterB: We could potentially link it to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements).

Comment: The scope of the site here seems drastically not in-line with what was requested; the "OK, So what can I ask?" section alone is 7 bullets and a little over a paragraph, as compared to the requested "no more than 4 bullets," and this answer suggests that even that is preceded by two paragraphs on what's out of scope.

Comment: @NexTerren I agree, I think this is not good text for the [**On Topic**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, which should be about what this site *is*, not what it *isn't*. I think something along these lines might be good to display when new users ask questions though, like what [Server Fault has when a new user goes to ask a question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice?).

Comment: @Rachel: The sooner new users get presented with what the site is *not* about, the more likely they are to actually read it.  After three to six sentences, the likelihood of them even seeing it degrades rapidly to zero.  It doesn't much matter to me how this is accomplished, or where the text is placed, so long as ***what we're not** is the very first thing they see after they click "Ask a Question."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand that, but most people that actively seek out the OnTopic page in the Help section usually go there because they already know something about SE, and want to know what is On Topic. I think this is a great idea to post on the Ask Question page for new users though. I know from my personal experience as a new user of many sites who doesn't like reading manuals, faqs, or help sections *before* I am invested in a community, this is where I would actually read and pay attention to the information.

Comment: @Rachel as far as I understand interstitial is a separate feature that needs to have a dedicated request to be enabled for the site ([example of such a request at Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5850/89077)). In the past SE management seemed to be rather reluctant about enabling it

Comment: @Rachel: This text can go on the [How to Ask](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page.  Shog has already told me that this is a moderator-editable page, and it is the one that ServerFault presents as their interstitial.  cc:@gnat

Comment: @gnat I think we would have a higher chance at getting such a feature added now with the upcoming name change and attention SE is paying to the site. Having a solid blurb of text already defined is also a point in our favor... I know from experience that great ideas are plentiful, but it's the ones that contain all the specific details already laid out that usually get implemented.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That would be a good spot for it too. You should update your answer to clarify that this text would be for How to Ask and a potential interstitial page when asking questions. I think my main objections to this (and that SE might share) is that it isn't really suitable for the On Topic page, which should be about what the site is, and that they specifically asked that we make our On Topic page shorter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey these are different pages indeed, with different content. I compared at SF: [http://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice?](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice?) - this is interstitial and [http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) - this is How To Ask

Comment: @Rachel: I already covered that at the bottom of my answer.  I have no problem with removing 'What we're not" for the on-topic page, or moving it to the bottom.  New users don't read that page anyway.

Comment: I've been thinking about this, and honestly I don't know if this will be needed after a name change. I'd like to keep it as a possibility if things don't improve, but I really think we'll see a huge difference from the name change alone, and this kind of thing would be overkill. Its great if we were keeping Programmers as a name, but unnecessary for Software Engineering in my opinion.

Comment: @Rachel: It's absolutely essential.  The current Help Center doesn't work because new users never see it, but even if they did, they will cherry pick it to make their question on-topic (I've seen it happen before).  It's critical that we tell people *what we're not,* right up front, very specifically highlighting the problem areas, so that there's no possibility of mis-interpretation.  Remember, we're trying to solve the problem of a high percentage of off-topic questions.  The title of the site is a good start, but it's not enough.  Don't lose your nerve now. :)

Comment: The were not a forum paragraph should go above we don't do troubleshooting...

Comment: Concerning the name, I have a very similar opinion as Thomas Owens - the term "engineering" gives IMHO a wrong impression on how software design works, but it will probably be a much better name than "Programmer's" and it has the potential to suit our needs for giving a better first impression about the site's scope. If the community chooses this name, I will support this.

Comment: ... the problem with the term "We are not a Forum" is that most people coming here for the first time is they do not not understand what that means, even if they read it three times. Heck, in a specific sense, we  *are* a Forum, this is just not a site where questions should be asked which lead to lengthy discussions.

Comment: i'm not very knowing, but where does algorithms and contests fall?

Comment: @ADG: Algorithms is already mentioned in my post.  If a question about a contest otherwise meets all of the other requirements (i.e. it is about Software Engineering), then it is on-topic.  Most likely, it won't be.

Comment: @DocBrown: True, but new people use the word "forum" here all the time, as if they do understand it.  "Which forum should I post my question?"  All they really need to know is "Don't bring the bad habits you learned in forums here and expect them to work."

Comment: I should have added I really like your comprehensive description of the site's scope, and it's limits. If certain licensing questions are on-topic or not may still be debatable (but I think also there are too few of them to give us a headache if we handle this per case, as we did in the past).

Comment: `Quality Assurance and Testing` -> sqa.stackexchange.com

Comment: @bish: Only if they "discuss" Unit Testing and TDD in depth there.

Comment: +1 for "☑  I have read and understand this page. No, really. I have."

Comment: I like this proposal, but think that "we will not do your homework" should be in the explicit things this forum is not. Also, "we will not give you the ammo you need to shoot your boss or your co-workers". By that, I mean the kind of questions having to do with "my boss (or co-workers) want to skin the cat a certain way, and I think it should be skinned this way.... please tell me why I am right or if I am wrong."

Answer (score 41):

How happy I am that this day has finally come!  These are my suggestions, some similarities to Snowman's answer with certain omissions and value-adds.

### Site Name

I favor the new site name, **Software Engineering**

I am neutral to the new site name, **Software Development**

I dislike the name, **Software Architecture** however as this can be considered a distinct subtype discipline of Software Engineering in general.  The site is far more than just Software Architecture.

### Opening Statement

> Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for professionals and students in software engineering and related fields who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software engineering, software architecture and software development.

### Scope

Relatively the same with a few tweaks I would mildly suggest.

- I am open to removing Software Licensing from on-topic.  Snowman makes good points that these questions are problematic most of the time and often in that fuzzy legal area.
- I am supportive of adding the following on topic scope statements like below

> Continuous Integration, Deployment and Dev Ops Strategies
>
> Software Release Management

These kinds of questions I think most people would agree if well formed would be a welcome addition to the site, however it would be nice to more explicitly state that this is a friendly area for such questions as well.

### Questions I would like Answered

I think Project Management questions are a fuzzy area in the sites scope right now.  Clearly if I were managing the build out of a data center this would not fall in the site scope.  If I were a tech lead on an Agile Scrum team then that is well established as on topic currently.  Agile and Project Management for software development projects in general are on topic at Project Management site.

Should questions about Agile, Scrum and other Project Management methodologies continue to be on topic or is this a distraction?  If they should be on topic then were is the definitive line drawn in the sand?  How do we accurately reflect this in our On Topic statement?

Comment: Wouldn't "Engineering Accreditation and Certification" fall into "career and education advice" which is off-topic? Or would you support making only those specific subtopics on-topic?

Comment: I have similar questions. If you start stripping away things that are currently on-topic, but may have a better home on a different site (quality assurance and testing to Stack Overflow and SQA depending, methodologies and processes to Project Management, licensing to Law and Open Source, algorithms and data structures to SO for implementation and Computer Science for theory), you end up with requirements, architecture and design, and configuration management. Now that the network has grown, I can argue that there are better homes for just about everything in our on-topic list.

Comment: @Snowman I concede that point.  It is a slippery slope.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I think this isn't a slippery slope.  It is well established that if I have a question needing help on an algorithm from a very very large community of programmers and software developers then I would ask on SO.  If I want a smaller community of software engineers I ask here.  If I have a theory question that has no substantial practical real world problem statement, it should be on CS.  If it is a question about CS principles to be applied to a clearly articulated applied real world problem then I should ask here.

Comment: As I said before, the only thing I said I was "open" to for removal was software licensing.

Comment: Would you be open to changing “for professionals and students” to something that makes clear that non-professional enthusiasts are welcome, too?

Comment: Where Agile/Scrum/PM questions should go depends on the perspective that the asker wants. If it is the perspective of a regular team member, then here would be the right site. If it is more the manager/scrum master/product owner perspective, then PM.se would be a better site.

Answer (score 21):

I believe our scope is mostly fine already. I think the issues this site has are not related to scope, but a desire to devolve from Q&A to an open-ended, discussion-friendly forum-like site. In other words, a partial or total revert to the [NPR days](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3412/).

I fully support our current scope and focusing on questions that are narrowly-scoped and invite objective answers, or at least good subjective answers. We need to buck the trend of being known as "that place where you can ask about your [green field or blue sky](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/) projects. These may be the types of questions that people need answered, but they are difficult to address in the Q&A format and are not interesting to the high-reputation users who provide the bulk of the useful answers on this site.

Clearly, our name does not help. It does not accurately reflect what this site is about. It invites questions that are not appropriate here. Furthermore, our [on-topic list](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is on the longer side compared to other Stack Exchange sites. It may not be the longest, but it is not very concise nor does it accurately convey the overall theme of the site.

To address these concerns, I advocate for the following three changes (two requested in Ana's meta answer plus one more):

#### Change our name to Software Engineering

What is in a name? "First impressions." *We are not about programming, nor are we a catch-all bucket for Programmers' issues*. Look at our on-topic list: we are about software engineering. "Programmers" evokes NPR-style questions in my mind. "Oh, I am a programmer and I have a question about some random topic. This site is called Programmers. I should load up the crap cannon and ask my question here." Nope.

#### Refactor the on-topic list

Remember earlier, I said our scope is fine but the list is verbose.

1. Software lifecycle: requirements, design, architecture, development methodologies, unit testing.
2. Software configuration management strategies (the way it is now, but make it clear that SCM *tool* questions are off-topic)
3. Algorithm and data structure concepts.
4. Software engineering and team management and processes.

This is primarily a restructuring of the current list into fewer bullet points that are more closely related, but there is one important change:

No more software licensing questions. These tend to be problematic, resulting in a zillion comments about whether a particular question is on-topic or not, or whether a programmer rather than a lawyer can answer it. We should avoid the whole debate and make them categorically off-topic. [Open Source SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) is in beta but doing well, and covers the majority of licensing questions that are currently on-topic here. Closed-source licensing questions typically end with "ask the vendor" anyway.

#### Site UI Redesign

Change the site design to something that "looks" more like software engineering, not a programmer's desk. I am awful with graphics design so I cannot recommend much, but we need a change here. Something that looks unfriendly to someone who wants to post a code dump, or ask a broad blue sky question with zero useful information.

#### Conclusion

I think this site is pretty much set up to be a good, useful site. We just need some guardrails to help guide people away from the broad, opinion-based questions and more toward the interesting design and software engineering questions that are already on-topic.

Comment: It's odd to say the software lifecycle and software engineering are on-topic but QA, which is part of both, is not. It's scope gerrymandering which we were warned against doing.

Comment: @Evan it's about we stop pretending that we discuss QA topics as true testers would. I am an ex-tester and QA stuff I've seen here is... softly speaking not at the best level from QA engineer perspective. As a part of development lifecycle it's good enough but not as a part of a discourse focused primarily on QA. I rarely visit QA.SE but what I see there, is so much better fit. About time to stop hijacking topics that are better covered at other SE sites

Comment: @gnat Overlap is totally fine; convoluted scope definitions like "software lifecyle but not QA (even though QA is a major part of the software lifecycle)" is how we got into this mess in the first place. We might not be the best place to ask QA questions, but so what? Like Thomas Owens is pointing out, if we take out all the things w'ere not the best at answering, there's precious little left here to ask. Either we stop scope gerrymandering everything that you don't happen to like or we might as well just shut the place down.

Comment: @Evan agree that overlap is fine; the one implied by SDLC is good enough for us already. If site had really strong presence in QA topics I wouldn't mind even stating it explicitly... but it hasn't

Comment: I don't see the point in carving out an exception for a class of questions that rarely gets asked here to begin with. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: regarding UI redesign, best "redesign" I could imagine seems to be happened already - [change to network wide rate limits](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/8034/31260). It's been over 3 weeks that I observe its impact and I can't believe my eyes, it feels almost as we're back to times prior to Spring 2014 in how debugging garbage is cut. Yes some stuff still leaks but so it was before 2014 and it was not very painful, and it is not very painful now. It's end of May and we aren't totally flooded by debugging garbage, unbelievable

Comment: @gnat I meant the UX: colors, images, look-and-feel, etc. not rate limiting questions.

Comment: I know I know. It's just that the rate limits change I mention, it seems to serve the goal of proposed UI change (cut the debugging garbage) so well that I suspect no UI can ever do

Answer (score 17):

#### On behalf of emeritus member MichaelT:

---

There's nothing wrong with the scope. The essence of it could be condensed to fewer bullet points, but such is of relatively minor consequence. The bullet points are more of an issue for moderators of other sites that check the help/on-topic before migrating... and the rare individual who read it before posting a comment of "belongs on Programmers."

The name, as demonstrated in the comments of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319375/ (10k link) is of some confusion to some people who post with the "but I'm trying to ask programmers this question."  A name such as software-engineering or software-architecture may have give them second thought about where to post the question.

However, it should also be pointed out with the above question that this demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of the Q&A model that SE uses - to the point that changing the name alone will not do it.

As mentioned in [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/) the thing that new users (and lets be honest - a significant chunk of the 70% closed questions are from new users) look at is other questions without regard for the "on hold" status of the question. There was a podcast awhile back by Joel and David about the intent of [Closed] - and part of that was as a head on a pike. I'm sure SE employees would more easily dig it out than I can. The mini-meta survey demonstrates that this is completely failing. One can refine the scope and change the name till the end of time - questions will be asked like the ones that show up when you go to the front page.

This brings up an awkward realization - the way to make the questions go away from immediate view is to down vote them heavily. This leads to the "why are you all so negative" posts which are not at all fun to deal with, especially without moderator and community manager support.

If one wants to cut down on the off topic questions - close and delete the unsalvageable posts quickly. Gnat likes to point out that triage on Stack Overflow helps with this. Failing the ability to prevent questions from showing up on the front page with triage, down votes, close votes, and 20k delete votes are the thing necessary to cut down on the off topic questions that reinforce the perception that this is where one is to ask such questions.

This brings up another awkward realization - the active pool of close votes and 20k delete votes is on the decline. And to this, no amount of UI, name change, fiddling with the help/on-topic, or trying to make a one sentence thing to put in the tour will accomplish significant amounts. Moderators will likely need to step up and more than just close and ignore the off topic questions - close and delete them - preferably quickly. Instead of 70% of the front page showing questions that one shouldn't ask, 70% of the front page should be showing questions that one should ask.

One might want to consider adjusting the privilege levels for a few months after the redesign, giving 10k or 15k users the ability to cast delete votes on questions that are less than a few days old... and reviving the 3 vote experiment again. The front page needs to reflect the scope and the both the moderators and the community at large needs to step up and make the site match the vision of what they want to see.

If there isn't any change to how (and who) people cast close votes; or the duration that an unsalvageable question remains visible on the front page, serving as a model for how to ask another question - the results from this exercise in scope, name, and design will not likely have the intended effect of consistently reducing the number of off topic questions asked.

There is another problem with the 'scope' though. It isn't about the scope itself, but rather the question of where does one draw the line with primarily opinion and too broad questions. Even with a more concise scope of Software lifecycle, Software configuration management, Algorithm and data structures and Software engineering and team management as described by Snowman, there are still questions that are primarily opinion or too broad that fit within this area of topicality.

This seems to be one of the more difficult and overlooked parts in this process of a name change - and these are the questions that have given the people who actively curate and moderate the site the most headaches. Without any guidance (and I'm not going to offer any here), questions along the lines of "how should I lay out my Git repo" or "what patterns/algorithms should I use to solve some problem" will still be asked and still consume too much community moderation and curation time and still be a point of contentious debate on meta.

Comment: good food for thought. Made me wonder how comes that [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions) pages aren't littered with "my servelet dosent work, help". Based on site name, they should be a natural target for half askers blocked at Stack Overflow, "my server isnt work and this is site about server I ask here about server why cant I. why you close! confusing site name!!!"

Comment: @gnat Server Fault has an active community that descends on those questions like vultures on a carcass. Programmers has _never_ been that active.

Comment: interesting. I can't see their deleted questions but [closed ones](http://serverfault.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes) do not indicate extraordinary active community - 8 of 10 newest closed questions I looked at turned out mod-closed

Comment: @gnat It's a combination of the name and the tag line. I worked in tech support for a while, and for a long time I would double-check the tag line of both ServerFault and SuperUser because I never could remember which site was which. ServerFault says "network admin", which immediately puts you in the right frame of mind. If they had been named "TechnicalSupport.SE" with a tag line of *"Server Fault is a question and answer site for IT people"*, they would be a lot more like us.

Answer (score 16):

I like [maple_shaft's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/1130), however wanted to write my own for reducing the [on-topic page's wall-of-text](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since it's far too long for a comment on his answer.

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> **Software Engineering** Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for professionals and students in software engineering and related fields
>   who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions
>   about software engineering, software architecture, and software
>   development.
>
> **If you have a question about...**
>
> - software architecture and design
> - development methodologies and processes
> - algorithm or data structure concepts
> - software release management
> - quality assurance or testing strategies
>
> **and it is not about...**
>
> - understanding, writing, or debugging code (check out [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead)
> - career, workplace, education, or lifestyle advice
> - [legal advice or aid](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/what-types-of-legal-questions-are-on-topic-here)
>
> ...then you're in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please make sure that your question is not [too broad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490) or [strongly
>   rooted in opinions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491). If you have questions that warrant an extended
>   discussion, feel free to [come to chat](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7248/how-do-you-get-20-rep-to-get-into-chat).
>
> Before asking, [look around](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been
>   asked. If you see similar questions, be sure to check out their
>   answers and differentiate your question from other, related questions.
>
> For more details, please see [our curated FAQ on Meta Programmers
>   Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq/info).

To summarize changes

- Replaced initial paragraph with tag line from maple_shaft's answer
- Reduced on-topic list. Its not to say those other items are not on-topic, but they can be generally lumped together with a different bullet point or are a part of the broader common definition of "software engineering". I am tempted to remove the QA&Testing bullet point as well, but I'll leave that up to someone else.
- Reduced the off-topic list. This is not to say those items are now on-topic, but I think they no longer will need to be explicitly mentioned in the On-Topic page as off-topic.
- Removed or reduced a lot of the remaining text.

Scope should not change. Even licensing questions can sit in a gray area where if the specific question falls under the general umbrella of software engineering, it's OK, but if it's too close to "legal aid", it's off-topic.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/8061/1204

Comment: Why not remove "students" and make it clear that users should have had formal training in Software Eng before using the site?

Comment: @Ian: Because that's not true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, then change the rules to make it true!

Comment: @Ian: No. We are not elitists. Who better to help than those who need help?

Comment: @Ian The students of today are the professionals of tomorrow. They're very important to keep a site growing and maintaining a healthy user base

Answer (score 11):

### Site Name

I've started to come around to the name "Software Engineering".

Although I still have some lingering objections regarding the overuse of the term "engineering" in software development, I think that the benefits would outweigh my personal objections. It does bring to mind a professional-oriented site that caters to people that work throughout the software development life cycle, from business analysts to developers to managers to leads. It also pairs nicely with Computer Science, especially since both correspond to the underlying academic disciplines.

### Tour and Tagline

> Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, practitioners, and researchers of software engineering. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about software development.

I ripped this from sites like Computer Science and Electrical Engineering. I removed the portion about "expert answers on conceptual questions about software development" since that can be confusing and I don't see how it's necessary. I tended toward the wording used on Computer Science.

> Software Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, practitioners, and researchers of software engineering.

The first line of the /help/on-topic page is just the first sentence of the /tour description, word-for-word.

### On-Topic Page

I'm shamelessly stealing this idea from Robert Harvey, but I think that we should do some minor refactoring and link to appropriate Wikipedia articles that define terms. Unfortunately, I don't think that we can get this down to "no more than four bullets, no multi-line comma-separated lists, no gerrymandering". I think we can avoid multi-line comma-separated lists and gerrymandering, but the discipline of Software Engineering is broad. Being clear about what is on-topic and what is off-topic (and what sites support questions about things that are off-topic) is essential and helpful.

I think that the shortest reasonable on-topic list would be something like:

> - [software requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements)
> - software [architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture) and [design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design)
> - [software quality assurance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance)
> - software [configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management), [build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) and [release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_management) management
> - software [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process) and [management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_management)

I removed "algorithm and data structure concepts", since I would consider that part of "software architecture and design". Evaluating and choosing various data structures and algorithms is inherently a design activity. I also removed "and testing" from "quality assurance and testing" since testing is one aspect of quality assurance, but we don't take all testing questions (such as, for example, writing or debugging unit test code). I also merged "software engineering management" and "development methodologies and processes" into "software process, methods, and management" since these three things are very tightly related.

[Like maple_shaft](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8058/4), I'd like to talk about software licensing. I recognize how important the topic is, but when it was added and clarified, neither the Law nor the Open Source Stack Exchange existed. It is something that software engineers operating in a professional environment should be aware of and do need to work in, and the IEEE does bury a small section on "Legal Issues" (referring to trademarks, patents, copyrights, trade secrets, professional liability, trade compliance, cybercrime) under "Software Engineering Professional Practice". At the same time, the IEEE also puts things like "Employment Contracts", team dynamics, working in multicultural environments, reading, writing, and presenting under "Software Engineering Professional Practice" and these are definitely off-topic here.

I recommend removing the "software licensing" line. The [Law Stack Exchange is graduating](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/congrats-law-se-will-be-graduating-soon?cb=1) and the [new rules for the graduation process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) will likely mean that Open Source won't end up closing in the foreseeable future. These sites can do a much better job of handling licensing questions (along with other types of questions) than we can.

> - understanding, writing, or debugging code (check out Stack Overflow instead) how to use specific tools
> - general workplace issues, office politics, and job hunting (ask on The Workplace instead)
> - open source philosophy, licenses, and open source communities (visit Open Source instead)
> - legal concepts, theory, and terms (check out Law instead)
> - what language/technology you should learn next, including which technology is better
> - what project you should do next
> - where to find a software library, tool, book, research paper, blog, forum, or other resource
> - product or service recommendations
> - career or education advice

The biggest change is that we start linking to Open Source and Law. Before we actually do this, we do need to consult with their communities and make sure it's OK. But since there are better sites, I think it's safe to punt these questions to the experts anyway.

Slight reordering of the things that are off-topic. We may want to check through the Meta questions that are currently linked and make sure they are correct. The biggest change is the removal of "personal lifestyle, including relationships and non-programming activities" - I'd hope that a distinct change to the site name would make this very explicit to visitors as your personal life is not Software Engineering.

We may want to also identify some other sites to point people to. We could link to Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations next to "product or service recommendations", as an example. There are also other sites that are related to software engineering that we don't identify as being off-topic (because it should be obvious) - Mathematics, Cross Validated/Statistics, User Experience, Information Security, Writers, Database Administrators, Code Review, Project Management (beta), Software Quality Assurance & Testing (beta), Computer Science, Engineering (beta), Law (beta), and Open Source (beta).

### Other

I would like to see a theme change on the site. Something that is more professional. I like the general idea of diagrams and models, but parts of the site do seem cartooney. I'd like to be crisper, more like the other science and engineering sites.

I'd like to look at methods for linking to related sites. Adding them to a Help Center page, like /help/on-topic, may work, but it would make that page much longer. I'd like to try to make Help Center pages smaller and less dense. It makes sense to point people to sites that they may not otherwise know about. Perhaps a Meta question that is part of the [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) would work.

Could we have a temporary box, similar to how the Law and Health sites do, but to talk about the changes? I suspect we'll have a summary Meta post after the name is changed, so just a brief overview and link to that.

Comment: I like your updated on-topic list, but I still think the off-topic list is far too long and could be greatly reduced. Also, I would prefer to have the tag line be about a subject, not a group of people. This site should be for students, practitioners, and researchers to obtain answers related to software engineering.

Comment: @Rachel The tagline is almost identical to what Electrical Engineering, Computer Science, and other professional sites use. If the site's title is "Software Engineering", I would hope that the questions and answers are about software engineering. If people don't get that...I don't know.

Comment: You're right, I'm probably just scarred from the overly broad name of "Programmers" and thinking in that context :) I think with a more specific site title, it wouldn't be as much of an issue.

Comment: I really like the idea of a meta-faq post containing all the SE sites that are tangibly related to this one, and linking to it in the faq. SO, Workplace, Law, Code Review, Security, etc. This is something we can do on our own though, and we don't need SE permission for it. It just needs someone with some initiative to create it :)

Answer (score 10):

**I am a software engineer.** I use StackOverflow to solve my daily problems. I am surprised so many are in favor of renaming to Software Engineering, as I can only see it leading to confusion.

I come here to learn software design, but taking a glance at the questions I can see there is more: workplace issues, software best practices, coding techniques, licensing, and some more—mostly software or system requirements from what I can tell. Eliminating the workplace issues as off-topic or historical, I think Software Design or Software Architecture covers the site's core while permitting the fringe topics like licensing. I believe the site leans more towards theory, so I prefer design as I think it's more closely related than architecture.

## **Name: Software Design**

I'd like to note that there are a number of questions about workplace practices for software engineers which may be why many favor the Software Engineering name. Some of those questions belong here, but a number belong on Workplace, and I'd rather a questioner had to research which site was the best place for her question than inviting the good *and the bad* here.

I feel a bit out of place declaring the scope of the site when I myself am an infrequent visitor, but if I may be so bold I would declare it as such:

- Software theory, design, best practices, and techniques
- Software architecture including software requirements and licensing

Ergo, off-topic questions would include:

- Help debugging code (try [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/))
- What tool, product, service, language, thing (these don't work well with our Q&A format)
- Questions with a social aspect (consider asking on [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/))

As far as what the tour should say, I can't think of any changes other than the name:

> Software Design Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professionals and students in software development and related fields who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about software design.

Comment: I agree Software Design describes the majority of the scope...but it fails to address other aspects such as configuration management or project management. As a result I think SE is better overall.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Some of those things belong better on ServerFault or Workplace, and the scope should explicitly include the relevant aspects. I'm flexible on rewording or clarifying that since I'm not so familiar there; I'm happy to accept that feedback.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I'm choosing to focus on the majority case since I don't want to draw in poor questions. That's not a great experience for anyone.

Comment: What about asking the best way to implement something that is already designed? That would be out of scope of for "Software Design" but in for "Software Engineering". I think renaming to that descopes things we want to keep in. Aside from that, some of the things you listed I wouldn't consider in-scope for software engineering -- workplace issues (most questions with a social aspect) would belong in Workplace.SE and licensing (with regards to opensource ones at lease) would belong in OpenSource.SE (although it's still in beta); reasoning is these really aren't related to software engineering.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: That raises another problem: "SE.SE" And now what does "SE" refer to? Poor choice IMO.

Comment: @CaptainMan Implementation is out of scope for design, and I think that's an accurate reflection of the site's scope. Software implementation? StackOverflow. Hardware implementation? ServerFault. Workplace practices? Workplace.

Comment: @CaptainMan We agree on workplace issues belonging on Workplace.SE; I think you misread that portion. Licensing questions I could go either way: I agree it's a bit out of place here, but I don't know if OpenSource.SE covers the same breadth we do, and I'm not sure if there's a more appropriate site to send them to. If the community can decide in or out, I can change my answer on licensing, but I'm inclined to leave it as-is unless there's significant feedback.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, its only an informal abbreviation anyway, what about SEng.SE (as in CompSci) instead?

Comment: @gbjbaanb: My point is that people are going to abbreviate, and it's going to cause confusion.

Answer (score 5):

## Site Name

### Software Development

This site is not really about Software Engineering. Naming it so would only attract legions of buzzword-mouthing, non-programmers, wannabe-managers, and unexperienced-college-students.

In the worst case scenario **it would kill all intelligent communication under a heavy layer of babbling about pigs and chickens**, this could mushroom to the extreme point of making the site useless.

This site is opinionated, *per se*, and I come here to read those 3rd party opinions and use them, to a certain extent, to form my own ones. It needs this degree of freedom that may (now, but it didn't use to) feel weird in the SE galaxy.

Software Development is a proposal that ''maple_shaft'' made, but he's not really backing it. I do, and I wish more would. **It keeps the same spirit as the "Programmers" moniker did.** Not precisely technical, but... meta-tecnhical discussions about the craft of programming, designing, developing software.

Comment: totally agree. If I want to argue about naming convention de jure or read another answer telling someone they aren't doing aglie/tdd/oop right I can do that at work

Answer (score 3):

Just like most if not all prior answerers I like the current scope of the site as it is. To me, primary reason to participate here is pretty much covered in two bullets in [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- software architecture and design
- development methodologies and processes

First bullet is probably also on-topic at Stack Overflow (hat tip to Robert Harvey) but it doesn't help me over there, because these topics are difficult to find and follow at SO. Given that I am not interested in asking and answering code troubleshooting questions and that my interest in reading these is quite specific and limited, I essentially have no other option but Programmers.

As for the second bullet, it is probably also somehow covered at Project Management but, again, this doesn't help. I am primarily interested in these topics from perspective of a developer, not a manager, that makes it so much more comfortable to have them here, on a site where development and architecture concerns are firmly within site scope. Besides, my interest in "pure management" topics is rather limited and I am not fond of participating in the site which has these as primary focus.

---

Other bullet points (except for licensing, more on it below), I would be comfortable if these aren't mentioned explicitly but instead assumed to be okay in the context of "my" bullet points: requirements, algorithm and data structures, quality assurance and testing, configuration management, software engineering management.

I understand that such implicit inclusion may make Programmers less of a welcoming home for some "pure forms" of QA and algorithms questions but such questions don't seem to be going particularly well here anyway, which makes it more of a theoretical concern. And, which is probably most important, such questions seem to have solid coverage at other SE sites which have them as primary focus (SQA, CS, TCS).

Licensing questions seem a bit tricky. I haven't yet seen compelling explanation of their fundamental relevance to "my" bullet points. But on the other hand I haven't yet seen compelling explanation for opposite either.

Because of that I am not going to change my voting habits if licensing isn't listed explicitly. I just won't vote close these questions - or more precisely will handle them per [current guidance](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7265/31260). I may change this approach later if I find that some other SE site holds these questions really well (like it happened to career topics at Workplace) but as of now this doesn't seem to be the case.

---

For the sake of completeness - since this question asks about site name - I don't care about it.

I had some reservations on this in the past when I saw people expecting this to help us against floods of debugging garbage and I wasn't sure that this would help and it looked like in case if this fails, this could damage site image. "Look, these suckers changed name of the site they had for 5 years only because they were scared by debugging spammers. And, you know, this didn't help them, bwa ha ha."

But what I observe for past few weeks made me feel much safer about that. It looks like recently introduced [network wide rate limits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/839601) cut the flow of debugging off-topic garbage and do this fairly efficiently and that site name just doesn't matter.

In the light of above, whatever name site community picks I will be fine with it.