# Is question about negotiating method on buying data on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I think it's on-topic, since the [negotiation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negotiation) tag exists, and one of its question ([How do I negotiate with a company to develop software?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/89960/192731)) is similar to the question of mine. However, that question was asked in 2011, and looking up in the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'm not sure if my question is on-topic or not. Further more, I'm aware of the proposal of changing the name of the site, and I don't feel like the proposed name best suit for me. After all, I just someone who code, not a qualified professional programmer.

**My draft question**: I'm a solo "programmer", and I need to buy data for my program. All of the vendors both ask me what is my budget to buy it, and the prediction of the number of users will use my program. How should I negotiate with them?

Comment: The presence of a tag is not a reliable indicator of topicality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: most probably not (I would expect the community on Programmer's to close it).

The fact an old question from 2011 was not closed so far should not bring you to the conclusion that the same question would be still on-topic today. The site and it's scope has changed since then. Today, general questions (like questions about service contracts, or how to negotiate them) which are not specifically about conceptual software development are typically closed quickly by the community here.

Moreover, the site will probably be renamed in future, and its scope description be more focused, read [this meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/new-site-name-and-scope-proposals) to inform yourself.

Comment: I has predicted this is the answer, though I expect it to be opposite :(. Do you know where should I ask this question?

Comment: @Ooker: when I was writing this answer, I was alread considering to add "no, I do not know where you can ask this, probably not on the SE network, maybe on Quora. You can also try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard)

Comment: @Ooker see [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Programmers. Where else can I ask it?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8066/31260)

Comment: This kind of question is better suited on Startups. See the meta there: [Is question about buying data on-topic?](http://meta.startups.stackexchange.com/q/310/9502)